# iPhone:Http POST request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http-post, nsurlrequest

I need to send  some details to a server from my iphone app.

I have details as `separate arrays of ID,name,quantity` and `strings with name,address,phone & email`.

I need to change the NSmutable array data into this JSON format

```
      [
            {"id":"139","name":"Samosa","quantity":"332","spice":"hot"},
            {"id":"149","name":"rice","quantity":"4","spice":"mild"},
            .....
      ]
```

My one doubt is 
`[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];`
Is the above line is enough to set the POST request.

How could I add the above details into the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSON serializer. You could use [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/). With SBJSON, the code will be like this:

```
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[[SBJsonWriter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *jsonParams = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:<your-NSArray>];
```

For adding this `jsonParams` to POST:

```
NSString *postData = [jsonParams stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:postURL];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough. You need also (minimum):

```
NSString *your_request_string = @"the thing in JSON format";
NSData *your_data = [your_request_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:your_data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [setHTTPBody:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableURLRequest) to add post data to your HTTP request object.
Use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html%22NSJSONSerialization%22) to serialize your array.

```
NSMutableArray *array = getSomeArray();
NSError *err;
NSData *json;

json = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:0 error:&err];
if (err) {
    // handle error
}

NSURL *url = getSomeURL();
NSMutableURLRequest *req;

req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:json];

// send your request
```